# How to add 30 mins to current timestamp?

Tags: php, sql, database, datetime

So basically I need to add 30mins to the current time and send it as a time stamp in database.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
$today = date("H:i:s");
```

I.E i need  current time : 10:00 sent time to database 10:30.
I know the codes in sending it to the database i just want to know how to add certain mins or seconds to the current time.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the database time for this:

```
now() + interval 30 minute
```

You could set a column with the value as:

```
update t
    set col = now() + interval 30 minute
    where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, but go with the database solution if possible:

```
$today = date("H:i:s", strtotime(“+30 minutes”);
```